# Interpret Objective C scripts at runtime on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, runtime, interpreter, objective-c-runtime

**Is there anyway to load an objective c script at runtime, and run it against the classes/methods/objects/functions in the current iPhone app?**

***MAJOR NOTE:*** The major reason I'd like to do this is to allow me to rapidly prototype an application, and then, after I'm done a major prototyping phase, take the scripts I was writing and compile them at build time instead. I don't ever plan on shipping an app with an objective c interpreter in it.

The reason i ask is that I've been playing around with [iPhone wax](http://github.com/probablycorey/wax), a lua interpreter that can be embedded in an iPhone app, and it works very nicely, in the sense that any object/method/function that's publically available in your Objective C code is automatically bridged, and available in lua.

This allows you to rapidly prototype applications by simply making the core of your app be lua files that are in the users documents directory. Just reload the app, and you can test out changes to your lua files without needing to rebuild the app in XCode - a big time saver!

But, with Apples recent 3.1.3 SDK stuff, it got me thinking that the safest approach for doing this type of rapid prototypeing would be if you could use Objective C as the interpreted code... That way, worst case scenario, you could just compile it into your app before your release instead.  I have heard that the lua source can be compiled to byte code, and linked in at build time, but I think the ultimate safe thing would be if the scripted source was in objective c, not lua. That way your source is always in objective c, regardless.

This leads me to wondering (i've searched, but come up with nothing) if there are any examples on how to embed an Objective C Interpreter in an iPhone app? This would allow you to rapidly prototype your app against the current classes that are built into your binary, and, when your about to deploy your app, instead of running the classes through the in app interpreter, you compile them in instead.

With the iPad and OS 4, bluetooth and virtual keyboards can work with iPhones and iPads... That's going to make this type of rapid prototyping something much more useful, at least for dev time. If you have an interpreter built into your app and have it on your iPad, for example, you can code against the interpreter while on the road, without XCode. And to me, the most useful way to get the source back to an "apple approved" state would be if the scripts were Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic Objective-C interpreter:

Check out the posting:

[Is there an Objective-C Interpreter for the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211404/is-there-an-objective-c-interpreter-for-the-mac)

Also:

http://forrst.com/posts/Beginnings_of_a_Objective_C_Interpreter-Tdl

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is really just C with a runtime and some syntactic sugar.  It's an inherently compiled language (I don't think there are any production-ready interpreters for C, although I might be wrong).

Xcode used to have a feature called [ZeroLink](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ZeroLink) to speed up compile time, but removed it in Xcode 3 because it caused too many bugs.

Comment: good point... I've clarified my question a bit, and my major intent would be to use this for rapid prototyping on an iPad while I'm on the road, kind of a portable XCode...

Comment: The point still stands.  There simply aren't any Objective-C interpreters, let alone embeddable ones.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly impossible, but it wouldn't be easy enough to be worth it. Objective-C isn't normally an interpreted language. This isn't insurmountable — interpreted vs. compiled is just an implementation choice in most cases. For example, Ruby is traditionally considered an interpreted scripting language, but MacRuby compiles it down to code just like Objective-C produces. So it would be possible to write an interpreter for Objective-C, but nobody has done this. You would have to write it yourself.

Also, the rules forbid interpreters other than Apple's Javascript interpreter. So far this hasn't been enforced on anyone, but if you're trying to be a very straight arrow, interpreted code is unfortunately out as well.

Comment: thanks for the comment... I've clarified my question a bit, as my main intent would be to rapidly prototype applications - which, given the iPad's fullsize virtual keyboard, would be very nice indeed! It'd be like you had a portable XCode with you (of sorts).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a couple worthwhile points to bring up:

1. Why *interpret* Objective-C code when you can *compile* it? I understand the "rapid prototyping" idea, but part of the reason to do that in, e.g., Lua, is because Lua is a much terser language than Objective-C. I don't know if interpreting Objective-C will have as much of a bonus.
2. If you want to have plugins or dynamically-loadable modules in your app, you can always compile them as a separate bundle and load them, using `NSBundle` or a similar mechanism.
3. All that said, I don't know of any Objective-C interpreters. You'd likely have to write your own. I'm not sure if it would violate Apple's guidelines or not: it'd still be Objective-C code, but I thought they had rules against interpreted code, too. (I suppose they never envisioned a hypothetical scenario in which *Objective-C* was interpreted, though.)

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit, as my main intent would be to rapidly prototype applications and not deploy this in a app for the appstore, but otherwise, point taken!

Comment: and to further clarify, i'd like to use this on an iPad, where there is no XCode, to allow me to do development work on the road, without XCode.

Comment: Interpreted language explanation From wikipedia  "An interpreted language is a programming language for which most of its implementations execute instructions directly, without previously compiling a program into machine-language instructions. The interpreter executes the program directly, translating each statement into a sequence of one or more subroutines already compiled into machine code.    

The terms interpreted language and compiled language are not well defined because, in theory, any programming language can be either interpreted or compiled."

Answer (score 1):

Ch is a commercial C/C++ interpreter.  It's made by a company called SoftIntegration.

Comment: does it work with Objective C? Objective C is neither C or C++

Answer (score 1):

Not on IPhone, but on Simulator, you can do this with
Dynamic Code Injection Tool
http://dyci.github.com/

There's also another tool, that works a little different way, but allows same functionality
http://injectionforxcode.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [cycript](http://www.cycript.org/). You can hook into apps, replace methods on the fly, change variables, you-name-it. It's an hybrid language between Objective-C and JavaScript.
You'll need to [jailbreak](http://jailbrea.kr/) your iDevice to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for `objc_msgSend()` and other parts of the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). You can essentially parse text and send it to the runtime.

Comment: While creating an Objective-C interpreter would certainly entail sending messages to objects, that would be without a doubt the most trivial part of the task.

Comment: thanks for the comment... i've played around with the objective c runtime a bit, and that was one of the things that got me thinking it might be possible to do this!