# Is there any sort of interactive Objective-C programming tool?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Objective-C Interpreter for the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211404/is-there-an-objective-c-interpreter-for-the-mac)

I'm doing lots of graphics programming for iOS using CGPaths + CALayers, etc. and previewing in the iPhone Simulator. All works fine but it is just so slow to view results - taking 20+ seconds each time to run the program in the Simulator - that tweaking and testing is getting very tedious (and it seems, alliterative).

Is there any sort of Objective-C tool which would enable me to enter lines of code and see results immediately?

Comment: How fast does it take to display the results on an iDevice?

Comment: Xcode? All programs must compile before you see the results, no? And trust me, 20 seconds per test is nothing. When you get into large-scale products with unit tests that take literally hours to run, that's when you'll be bugged by tweaking values in certain places.

Comment: It's not a problem of slow to display - it's the loading into the Simulator environment and the time it takes for that to get up and running. Loading onto the device is even slower.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - but I've seen that there are graphics tools which output Obj-C code so they must be generating code instructions on the fly, right?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is a way to vary some parameters of your drawing and see the results immediately without having to recompile. I don't know of any tools that do that, but you could do it yourself by making a system where you can set the parameters you want. For example, maybe some gesture brings up a view that has some sliders or text fields in it, and you can change the values, hit "OK" and it re-renders with the new values. It would only be in the debug version so users never see it. You'll probably have to roll your own in this case.